# Understanding of the output of LE Read Advertising Physical Channel Tx Power command

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

Recently I am working on broadcasting BLE advertising from a Raspberry Pi. Note that most parts have been done and I can receive the advertising message from another Raspberry Pi. The only thing I am not clear is how to read the TX power level, so the TX power information could also be sent.

Based on the [Core Specification](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/bluetooth-core-specification/) (Section 7.8 Part E, Vol. 4), I learned that

```
sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0007
```

is the command to read the TX power level. But I can't figure out the meaning of the output, which is

```
< HCI Command: ogf 0x08, ocf 0x0007, plen 0
> HCI Event: 0x0e plen 5
  01 07 20 00 0C
```

During these days playing with different commands, I can understand part of them. For example, `plen` probably means the parameter length. `0x0e` means the HCI_Command_Complete (Sec. 7.7.14, Part E, Vol. 4). `07` in the last line is the input ocf. My question is: Does `00` mean the command succeeded and `0C` gives the transmit power level? Or `0C` is Command Disallowed Error code?

Furthermore, I would like to know if someone could provide a document explaining all of the meaning of the codes in the output message `HCI Event`.

Thank you so much in advance.

Note: Somehow my previous question was closed by saying it belongs to https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ site. But I think the question is more related to the Bluetooth Standard and bluez. And I do see lots of related questions on this site. Please let me know if I understand wrongly.

Comment: If you run "sudo btmon" in another terminal while you run your test commands, it should decode all hci messages.

Comment: Wow! It works perfectly! It shows that: HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 5                 #2 [hci0] 19.810302
      LE Read Advertising Channel TX Power (0x08|0x0007) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
        TX power: 12 dbm (0x0c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run "sudo btmon" in another terminal while you run your test commands, it should decode all hci messages.

Comment: Hi Emil, first I want to thank you for your answer. It helps me a lot! In addition, I want to ask a further question here. In the btmon, it shows that TX power is 12 dBm (0x0c). Is it just because 0x0c is 12 in decimal, or is there a formula to calculate the power in dBm based on the hex value? Thank you!

Comment: It should simply be read as a signed 8-bit integer. See the hci section in the standard.

Comment: Got it. Thank you Emil!

Answer (score 0):

Chang: what you see in the response is

0x01        Inquiry Complete event, event code

0x07 0x20   op code of the command you sent (after some bit twiddling OGF & OCF)

0x00        status code, 0x00 is OK

0x0C        TX power level 0x0C == 12 decimal

but now a question: Chang reports a reading of 0x0c dBm. 
on my box I see 0x07 dBm.

Which both seem to be incredibly high values.... On the scanner I get RSSI of
-49 dBm (with the phone almost on top of the beaming laptop - some DELL Ubuntu
with bluez)

Given the reading of 0x07 dBm my iBeacon scanner shows an incredible distance drop
of 179526552.90 m :-)

Any ideas why hcitool/bluez/Ubuntu would return a bad value to LE Read Advertising Physical Channel Tx Power command?

Comment: Hi Carl. Thanks for your explanation. And you asked a great question. I also thought about it when I saw the TX power is 12 dBm. This is higher than I expected. Also, from the receiver side, it reported the RSSI was between -40 and -60 and the average RSSI was about -54 dBm when the distance between the transmitter and receivers was 3 meters. I am not sure if the TX Power provided by hcitool is bad or not. I may need some time to look into the link budget. So I can't answer you right now. But I am glad to know this is not a special case that only happened to me.

Comment: I've done some more digging. looks as if I had an Intel WiFi/BT chip in my box.
https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/94150/intel-dual-band-wireless-ac-8265.html
The specs allow TX power to be up to 20 dBm which corresponds to 100 mW and is apparently BT class 1 radio.
So our readings appear legitimate. what iBeacon does in terms of distance computing by comparing TX Power & RSSI, I don't know

Comment: found an explanatio on TX Power. it is *not* the power used in the sending chip, but the power measured 1 m away....
see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37268460/beacon-why-we-need-calibrate-tx-power